# How to use Django iterator with value list?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset

I have Profile table with a huge number of rows. I was trying to filter out profiles based on `super_category` and `account_id` (these are the fields in the model Profile).
Assume I have a list of ids in the form of `bulk_account_ids` and `super_categories`

```
list_of_ids = Profile.objects.filter(account_id__in=bulk_account_ids, super_category__in=super_categories).values_list('id', flat=True))

list_of_ids = list(list_of_ids)

SomeTask.delay(ids=list_of_ids)
```

This particular query is timing out while it gets evaluated in the second line.
Can I use `.iterator()` at the end of the query to optimize this?
i.e `list(list_of_ids.iterator())`, if not what else I can do?

Comment: As long as you're forming a `list()`… no. More generally, as long as you need to pass all actual objects into `SomeTask.delay`, no. That simply requires all objects to be read into memory from the database, which is what takes time. If `SomeTask.delay` would accept something other than the actual list of actual objects, then you could do something there.

Comment: @deceze Does it make sense to use iterator like this `queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True).iterator()` If we want to run a queryset in a loop?

Comment: You don't want to send a ton of arguments to a celery task, first of all, because those will get stored in your queue, which isn't great. As for values_list, I think the answer is to use `.only('pk').iterator()` instead, but I don't think it's good practice to pass a queryset to a celery task either, so probably best to do that in the celery task too.